# need and use of weak entities in ER diagrams

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have two entities

`textbook(ISBN primary key, name, auhor etc...)
is published by
publisher(name, number_of_books_published etc...)`

My publisher is a weak entity.

1. Why do I need this entity to be kept as weak and not making it strong? What is its significance?
2. If I add BookISBN primary key to publisher it will become a strong entity. What would be the difference between the two designs then?

Answer (score 0):

1) There is no way to answer that question without the requirements of the project.  Weak means the entity cannot be identified by its attributes alone.  I would agree publisher is likely weak since neither name or number_of_books_published or any combination thereof is guaranteed to be unique.

2) Adding BookISBN to publisher would not be correct.  The one-to-many relationship happens in the other direction; i.e. a publisher publishes many books - this is confirmed by the number_of_books_published attribute of publisher (which is arguably not necessary since you can always calculate that value).

In theory (I don't know if this really happens (I've never seen it)), a textbook could be published (printed is more likely) by more than one publisher so having the primary key of publisher in textbook would make textbook a strong entity.  I find this unlikely so a better solution is a relation table - i.e. PublisherBook which holds the primary keys of publisher and textbook this way a publisher can publish many books AND a book can be published by many publishers (which may play a more important role over time say one publisher goes out of business and the book is not published by a different publisher).  In this model you have the possibility of maintaining "history" without say updating the PublisherId on the textbook table and loosing the previous publisher.